# Why does Shelly's face glow?

Tags: hemlock-grove

In season 1 of Hemlock Grove, when Roman affectionately touches Shelly's face, that part of her face briefly gives off a blue glow- why does this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Hemlock Grove wiki,](http://hemlockgrove.wikia.com/wiki/Luminescence) this is a side-effect of the experiments Johann Pryce was conducting in order to "ressurect" Shelley as an infant.  The details of what happened to Shelley when she was younger are not really clearly explained in the TV show, IIRC, but perhaps there's more detail about this in the book upon which the show was based.  (I haven't read the book myself.)